# Rails Testing: Why do Association References Make Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-4

Learning Rails Testing here

I am getting errors in rails default tests.

Here is one of the 3 errors related to this controller. All errors http://pastie.org/9756790

```
RundataControllerTest#test_should_get_edit:
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
    app/views/rundata/_form.html.erb:15:in `block (2 levels) in _app_views_rundata__form_html_erb___4420969876653961991_47893480'
    app/views/rundata/_form.html.erb:15:in `block in _app_views_rundata__form_html_erb___4420969876653961991_47893480'
    app/views/rundata/_form.html.erb:1:in `_app_views_rundata__form_html_erb___4420969876653961991_47893480'
    app/views/rundata/edit.html.erb:3:in `_app_views_rundata_edit_html_erb__2870890776683796725_47932520'
    test/controllers/rundata_controller_test.rb:33:in `block in <class:RundataControllerTest>'
```

Here is the line that is creating one of 5 errors in my test. See all Culprits below

```
<%= f.select(:run_id, Run.all.collect {|r| ['Run:' + r.id.to_s + ' for ' + r.company.name + ' to start on ' + r.start_date.strftime("%b %d, %Y"), r.id]}, :selected => params[:run]) -%>
```

Here is my companies.yml fixtures

```
<% 500.times do |c| %>
company_<%= c %>:
  name: <%= "company #{c} name" %>
  street: <%= Random.new.rand(1000..9999).to_s + ' ' + (0...10).map { ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join  + ' street' %>
  city: <%= (0...20).map { ('a'..'z').to_a[rand(26)] }.join %>
  state: <%= "MN" %>
  zip: <%= Random.new.rand(10000..99999) %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my runs.yml fixtures

```
one:
  start_date: 2014-09-25
  end_date: 2014-09-25
  company_id:
  building: 1
  paid: false
  stage: MyString
  material_total_lbs: 1
  employees_needed: 1
  is_test: false
  requirements: MyText

two:
  start_date: 2014-09-25
  end_date: 2014-09-25
  company_id:
  building: 1
  paid: false
  stage: MyString
  material_total_lbs: 1
  employees_needed: 1
  is_test: false
  requirements: MyText
```

Here is my rundata.yml fixtures

```
one:
  run_id:
  date: 2014-09-23
  building: 1
  machine: MyString
  material_weight: 1.5
  time_mins: 1.5
  rate_lb_hr: 1
  mill_amps: 1
  class_amps: 1
  mill_liner: MyString
  beater_plate_size: MyString
  mill_rpm: 1
  class_rpm: 1
  feeder_type: MyString
  feeder_setting: 1.5
  feeder_aug_diameter: 1.5
  tlgs_set: 1.5
  air_pressure: 1
  temp_mill_out: 1
  temp_prod_out: 1
  temp_ambient: 1

two:
  run_id:
  date: 2014-09-23
  building: 1
  machine: MyString
  material_weight: 1.5
  time_mins: 1.5
  rate_lb_hr: 1
  mill_amps: 1
  class_amps: 1
  mill_liner: MyString
  beater_plate_size: MyString
  mill_rpm: 1
  class_rpm: 1
  feeder_type: MyString
  feeder_setting: 1.5
  feeder_aug_diameter: 1.5
  tlgs_set: 1.5
  air_pressure: 1
  temp_mill_out: 1
  temp_prod_out: 1
  temp_ambient: 1
```

The relationships are all has_many -> <-belongs_to

Company -> <- Runs -> <- Rundatum

It appears to me that these statements throughout my code are the culprits.

```
@company = rundatum.run.company

r.company.name 

r.company.name

material.rundatum.id

@material.rundatum.id
```

Can rails test traverse associations?
I would guess that is has something to do with fixtures not containing keys for the relationships?

Any guidance would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have at least one `Run` object without `company` at your db. Then you get `udefined method 'name' for nil:NilClass`.

You can fix the issue changing `r.company.name` with `r.company.try(:name)`. Also you can remove this records and prevent save Run without Company.

Also, you can prevent `n + 1` issue, with `Run.includes(:company).collect` instead of `Run.all.collect`, you can find more information [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations)

How to work with associations on fixtures: [see point 2.3.2](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures).

On runs.yml change `company_id:` with `company: company_1`, and it will do the trick.

Comment: In my runs fixture `company_id:` is blank for both fixtures. From my understand rails handles this association when blank. My Companies fixtures also have no `id:` entry which I believe auto generates.